# NSString stringWithFormat not working with special chars like currency symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, stringwithformat

I have been having a lot of trouble with `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` method as of late. I have written an object that allows you to align N lines of text (separated by new lines) either centered, right, or left. At the core of my logic is `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat`. I use this function to pad my strings with spaces on the left or right of individual lines to produce the alignment I want. Here is an example:

```
NSString *str = @"$3.00" --> 3 dollars
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8s", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]] --> returns --> "   $3.00"
```

As you can see the above example works great, I padded 3 spaces on the left and the resulting text is right aligned/justified. Problems begin to arise when I start to pass in foreign currency symbols, the formatting just straight up does not work. It either adds extra symbols or just returns garbage.

```
NSString *str = @"Kč1.00" --> 3 Czech Koruna (Czech republic's currency)
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8s", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]] --> returns --> "  Kƒç1.00"
```

The above is just flat out wrong... Now I am not a string encoding expert but I do know `NSString` uses the international standardized unicode encoding for special characters well outside basic ASCII domain.

How can I fix my problem? What encoding should I use? I have tried so many different encoding enums I have lost count, everything from `NSMACOSRomanEncoding` to `NSUTF32UnicodeBigEndian`.. My last resort will be to just completely ditch using stringWithFormat all together, maybe it was only meant for simple UTF8Strings and basic symbols.

Comment: You will not get lucky with that attempt. Switch over to NSNumberFormatter. That is designed for exactly that purpose including coverage of locales where the currency is prefix and where it is suffix, including local style representation of negatives etc.

Comment: Yes, I think I am just going to switch from using stringWithFormat. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to represent currency, is a lot better if you use a `NSNumberFormatter` with currency style (`NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`). It reads the currentLocale and shows the currency based on it. You just need to ask its string representation and append to a string.
It will be a lot easier than managing unicode formats, check a tutorial [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/14/using-number-formatters.html)

Comment: Yeah @Andrea I agree that NSNumberFormatter is the way to go for currencies... But my object should align any text/string. I dont want to have to write more specialized code to handle a currency symbol case, there is just not enough value add there. Maybe the better approach is to just use NSString's padSpace method and forget using stringWithFormat all together. I am trying to just make this agnostic to generic NSString's, any string passed in should be justified.

Comment: Probably best to avoid stringWithFormat here.

Comment: I must be honest and say that I don't get the issue totally, for instance why did you create a specific object to show text and didn't use a label or a textview with attributed string? Coding strings can be really a pain

Comment: Its too much to explain and id rather not get into those details because it is outside the scope of the question at hand. My real question was just why couldnt I specify a stringEncoding for "stringWithFormat:" that just worked for currency symbol characters. Clearly the answer to that question is you just do not do that and its not possible without getting your hands extremely dirty. Cleanest way is to go through NSNumberFormatter which I had researched before. Was just wondering if anyone knew of a encoding way to do this

Comment: Pay attention that in the new version of XCODE there is a bug in the simulator, locale will not change if you set it in the settings ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the required result

```
 NSString *str = @"Kč1.00";

str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%8@",[@" " stringByPaddingToLength:3    withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0],str];
```

Out Put : @"   Kč1.00";

Comment: some thing wrong with my answer or I did not understand the question ?

Comment: Why would you propose such a convoluted answer? I am simply asking which encoding should I use so I can just simply use stringWithFormat.. OR if stringWithFormat is not the way to go... Also your solution is not a dynamic one, it seems to only fit the purpose of your example.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more trick to achieve this -
If you like use it :)

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8s%@",[@"" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],str];
```

This will work too.